# Im using Advanced custom fields, but how can I let my jquery loop through rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script:

```
<textarea id="textareabox">
<span id="correcto"></span>
<span id="incorrecto"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateform() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');
  var word = 'this is the answer';
  var word2 = "This could be the answer aswell";
  var textValue = textarea.value.toLowerCase();

  if (textValue.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = "this is the answer";
    return true;
  }

  if (textValue.indexOf(word2) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = "This could be the answer aswell";
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("incorrecto").innerHTML = 'Incorrect!';
  }

}
</script>
```

The scripts loop through 2 custom fields:

answer1
answer2
if the answer is not correct it will say incorrect!

But with this script I can only have 2 answers, I change this by adding an extra answer button, answer3 or answer4 but this is not desirable.

I rather have the script to loop through every row in answer1:

Answer1:

this is the answer
this could be the answer well
also this
and this
this
and again this could be

And if there are no more rows it says Incorrect! this way I can add way more answers.

But I don't know where to start for this, can only create extra "If"'s Im calling the custom field in the PHP from, so how does the javascript know it are extra's rows and not a complete answer 4 lines? How can I let javascript loop through the rows.

Could someone help me on my way?

In this script I'm using custom fields
This is the real script I'm using, but i want it to loop through rows until no line is left and then say incorrect!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php global $outputvali_of_this_page; ?>
<?php global $answerbutton2_of_this_page; ?>

function validateform() {

  s = document.getElementById("textareabox").value;
  s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
  s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
  s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");

  document.getElementById("textareabox").value = s;

  var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');
  var word = '<?php echo $answerbutton_of_this_page; ?>';
  var word2 = "<?php echo $answerbutton2_of_this_page; ?>";
  var textValue = textarea.value.toLowerCase();

  if (textValue.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($outputvali_of_this_page); ?>;
    return true;
  }

  if (textValue.indexOf(word2) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("correcto").innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($outputvali_of_this_page); ?>;
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("incorrecto").innerHTML = 'Incorrect!';
  }

}
</script>
```

Website for more: 
https://www.baswijdenes.com/powershell/using-help-system-powershell-practice-1-0/using-the-help-system-powershell-practice-1-2/

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question (here on Stack Overflow, not on your own website or a code sharing site). It would be preferable if you included the rendered HTML.

Comment: There is no problem? It's working as it should, but the issue lays with the rows in custom fields > javascript

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. If it's working as it should, then what are you asking? My point is that if you want help with making something work, you need to show us what's not working.

Comment: If you set for example the same class to all inputs you can use `querySelectorAll()` which returns array of elements. Then loop through it using `for` and as second argument you can use `.lenght` property (every array has it).